# Automatic restart of cron job using quartz in grails on server restart

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz plugin for cron scheduling in my grails project.
In my app the user gives a script and cron configuration which I set as cron using quartz.

But when I restart the server these cron jobs do not start.
Do I have to manually create these cron jobs again or there is a way to automatically store and restart them.

Here is my Quartz Job

```
class RscriptJob {
    def execute() {
        println "hello"
    }
}
```

Here is the controller which receives request from user through view to set up a cron

```
class UploadsController {
   def upload() {
      def cron=params.cronString
      RscriptJob.schedule(cron)
   }
}
```

The cron is scheduled. Now when I restart the server the cron doesnt starts.
I am storing cron info in db and can use it to set cron again on startup.

But I want to know if quartz has inbuilt functionality to support it.

Comment: Can you post your code.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can trigger DailyJob from your bootstrap.groovy wich is executed on startup, here is the place to schedule your jobs

```
    class BootStrap {


        def init = { servletContext ->
            def cronExpression = "*/10 * * * * ?"
            DailyJob.schedule(cronExpression)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot do that as the crons are created by end users. I cannot go and add crons manually in bootstrap.groovy

Comment: well i dont know how your jobs-domains look like or your database, but of course you could get all relevant data from the database instead of hardcoding it

Comment: Please see the code. I believe this will help you to understand my question. Thanks